# Uniform Convergence of the following series

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^2}{n+1}$$

is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ but not on $[0,\infty]$

I have tried using M-Test, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n}} {n+1}$ is convergent by alternating series test. Let its sum be $S$. It follows immediately that the given series converges uniformly to $Sx^{2}$ for $x$ bounded. [Just write down the definition of uniform convergence]. If the series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ then $\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n+1} x^{2}$ must tend to $0$ uniformly. This is false since $|\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n+1} x^{2}|=1$ when $x=n+1$.